# Swift wont recognize my type conforms to a protocol when it's an optional

Tags: swift, generics

I have a situation like so:

```
protocol Vehicle {}

struct Car: Vehicle, Decodable {}

func doSomethingWith<T>(type: T.Type) {
  if let vehicle = type as? Vehicle.Type {
    print("Nice, I detected that my type was a vehicle: \(vehicle)")
  } else {
    print("Ah, my type is a vehicle wrapped in an optional! \(type)")
  }
}
```

and I call it with:

```
doSomethingWith(type: Car.self)
doSomethingWith(type: Car?.self)
```

It will output:

```
Nice, I detected that my type was a vehicle: Car
Ah, my type is a vehicle wrapped in an optional! Optional<Car>
```

This is surprising to me. I would expect `let vehicle = type as? Vehicle.Type` to work in both calls to `doSomethingWith`, but because the second call passes an optional, my `doSomethingWith` function is unable to determine that this type conforms to `Vehicle` protocol. It makes sense, since the `Optional` class doesn't conform to it, the wrapped element in my optional does.

Is there some way I can modify `doSomethingWith` to (optionally) extract the inner type if an optional is passed to it such as in my second example?

Comment: This sounds a little like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain why you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you trying to achieve but instead of passing the Vehicle type you should just create a generic type, constrain it to Vehicle type, accept an optional parameter and switch its instance. Something like:

---

```
protocol Vehicle {}

struct Car: Vehicle, Decodable {
    let name: String
}
struct Truck: Vehicle, Decodable {
    let name: String
}
```

---

```
func doSomethingWith<T: Vehicle>(vehicle: T?) {
    switch vehicle {
    case let car as Car:
        print(car.name + " is a car")
    case let truck as Truck:
        print(truck.name + " is a truck")
    default:
        print("none of the above")
    }
}
```

---

```
let optionalCar: Car? = Car(name: "Ferrari")
let truck = Truck(name: "Peterbilt")

doSomethingWith(vehicle: optionalCar)
doSomethingWith(vehicle: truck)
```

---

This will print:

> Ferrari is a car
> Peterbilt is a truck

Comment: I think this is clean and a great approach, but I guess what I'm really asking is why can't I do either `if let vehicle = type as? Vehicle.Type` or `if let vehicle = type as? Optional<Vehicle>.Type` to cast my `Optional<Car>.Type` into an `Optional<Vehicle>.Type`? I would've thought it would work since `Car` conforms to `Vehicle`.

Comment: @dontforget `Car` conforms to Vehicle. `Optional<Car>` doesn't